# android query rows on table from multiple strings or list<string>

Tags: android, sqlite, multi-select

I have implemented a multi choice mode recyclerview where I want to query rows from the table containing the genres that user have selected. I display the list of genres available and then user will be able to select one or more genre. After that, once user is satisfied with the genres selected, the user should get a list of musics based on the genres they just selected. When I tried to query i don't get any results.

How do i query a row containing values inside a `List<Genre>`?  Please help or any suggestions.

This is my query method

```
   public List<Music> getMusicBasedOnGenre(List<String> genre) {
        List<Music> musicList= new ArrayList<>();
        sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT a.music_title AS MusicTitle"
                + ", GROUP_CONCAT(t.genre) AS Genre FROM music AS a"
                + " LEFT JOIN genre_tags AS gt ON gt.id_music = a.music_id"
                + " LEFT JOIN genre AS g ON g.genre_id = gt.id_genre"
                + " WHERE g.genre LIKE '%" + genre + "%'"
                + " GROUP BY a.music_id, a.music_title", null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                music.setTitle(cursor.getString(0));
                musicList.add(music);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }
        return musicList;
    }
```

This is the music table

```
    ------------------------------------------------------
    |  id  | music_title  |  artist  |     genre         |
    ------------------------------------------------------
    |  1   |  I love you  |   John   |   pop, rnb, jazz  |
    |  2   |  Fall        |   Hank   |   rnb             |
    |  3   |  Marry Me    |   Joe    |   jazz, rock      |
    ------------------------------------------------------
```

If I selected rnb, pop as genres
query result should display

```
I love you
Fall
```

This is the code to get the list of strings I selected.

```
List<String> genre= (List<String>)bundle.getSerializable("selectedGenre");

        assert genre!= null;
        String a = "";
        for (Genre g: genre) {
            a = a + g.getGenre() + "\n";
        }
```

This is the list value

```
List<String> genre = "rnb, pop, reggae";
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @mr.icetea can't get row results with the query

Comment: Try change `" LIKE '"%+ genre+%"'"` to `" LIKE '%"+ genre+"%'"`

Comment: you can loop on your list and add conditions using `OR`,  or you can use `IN` to search in a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

A valid query with `LIKE` clause should look like this,

```
SELECT * FROM music WHERE genre LIKE '%genre%'
```

Change your query from,

```
"SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_MUSIC + " WHERE " + KEY_GENRE + " LIKE '"%+ genre+%"'"
```

to

```
"SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_MUSIC + " WHERE " + KEY_GENRE + " LIKE '%" + genre+ "%'"
```